# ID for a newly saved backbone.js model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Backbone.js makes a POST request when a new model is created and saved, but it doesn't consider the model to be saved (i.e, further saves result in PUTs not POSTs) until the model has an id.. how should the server return the ID of a newly created model so that backbone.js can set it (i.e, how should it respond to the initial POST)?

If backbone.js doesn't handle that, I assume the best way to do it is using the success handler to set the ID?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options.  The first is to return the same JSON structure for a POST request as you would a GET request for the show action (returning a single item.)  This uses a single request.

From the [documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-41):

> Set a hash of model attributes, and sync the model to the server. **If the server returns an attributes hash that differs, the model's state will be set again.**

The other option is to trigger a fetch on your collection after you save.  This will take more than 1 request though and will always be less efficient.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're saying if I return a fully formed model with an ID as a response to the inital POST, backbone.js will change the saved model's attributes to the returned attributes? Are you sure?

Comment: This answer does not make grammatical sense -1

Comment: @reach4thelasers, specifically, which part?

Comment: Most of the first sentence.  Do you mean to say: "return the same JSON structure FROM a POST request as you would from a GET request"?  Or perhaps "return the same JSON structure FROM a post request as you would FROM a show action"?  Sorry if I'm splitting hairs but read the answer multiple times and couldn't make sense of the grammar.

Comment: @reach4thelasers that doesn't really mean the same thing as my original post.  I have added the word request to make it more obvious, but you return data for a POST request, not from it.

Comment: Note that the new values are only set after the request has been done, so you should use the `success` callback function of the `save()` function. See http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save